# Why is my layout displayed wrongly on Xperia Z?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with layout rendering on Xperia Z. I have 2 buttons on layout which should take the size of its parent. Unfortunately, the phone can not do that. This is my layout code :

```
<RelativeLayout>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        class="android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_View_Pager"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="X"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_2"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_1"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_2"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right"
        android:layout_below="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_1"/>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_View_Pager_Indicator"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_View_Pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`RelativeLayout`s with ID `View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left` and `View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right` are displayed wrongly.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: A screenshot can make this problem much simpler. Please fix also the xml and remove everything nonrelated like the *gone* views.

Comment: i added screen application

Answer (score 0):

As rekire mentioned, a screen shot will help for sure.
But I've spotted a few problems with you layout. first one being the parent RelativeLayout, which you closed right away. So correct that first of all.
And the other two layouts with ID *View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left* and *View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right* are being positioned in the layout with reference to *View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_2* and *View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_1* whose visibility is set to gone. I guess that is what is causing the problem. I think you want it below the view with id "*View_Pager_Layout_View_Pager*". Please rectify that and see if the problem is solved or not.

**EDIT**:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="X"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left"/>

<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right"/>

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right"/>

 <view
            android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            class="android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"
            android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_View_Pager"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_View_Pager_Indicator"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_View_Pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hvnt tested it. I just edited it in a notepad. So just try it out n tell me if works or not?

Comment: I want to show buttons with ID @ + @ + id/View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_2 and id/View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_1 just in time for an event because they are hidden, and my buttons with ID @ + id / View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Left and @ + id / View_Pager_Layout_Arrow_Right to be below them

Comment: I changed the visibility of the Exit Button 1 and Exit_Button_2. No change

Comment: I have added some code. try it n tell me if it helps.

Comment: I noticed that for each element that has a set height for match_parent it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately android:layout_above is not working. My View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_2 and View_Pager_Layout_Exit_Image_Button_1 is not visible. My layout on other phones is rendered correctly with android:layout_below